# Strange error using GWT canvas

Tags: javascript, gwt, html5-canvas

I created a website using Canvas on the client side to display animations. Sometimes it happens that the animations stop moving out of a sudden, so I ran the application in debug mode and got this strange error:

```
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.HostedModeException: Something other than an int was returned from JSNI method '@com.google.gwt.dom.client.ImageElement::getWidth()': JS value of type undefined, expected int
```

What could be the reason for this behavior? How can a function suddently undefine its return type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be alright.
This is a known chrome GWT plugin issue. This happens sporadically without any rule, the easiest solution is to use Firefox for debugging - it's more stable.

Here is the link for issue discussion: [click here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5778)

Comment: Thanks for your Reply! Good to know that, altough the original error that my animations stop working still remains. Lets see if I can find the real error using Firefox.